# How to extract part of the *original* text from JSON with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

*PLEASE, don't edit the question for me. My question is on String manipulation, changing the flow of text can very likely change the meaning of the question and cause confusion.*

*The problem can be viewed as a String manipulation problem. But I expect a solution in Jackson to solve my problem.*

---

Suppose I have received a String `{"payload":{"foo":"bar","ipsum":["lorem","lorem"]},"signature":"somehmacsign"}`. When it's displayed, it's like:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "ipsum": [
            "lorem",
            "lorem"
        ]
    },
    "signature": "somehmacsign"
}
```

How can I extract its substring from 11th character `{` till the `}` just before `,"signature"`. Namely, `{"foo":"bar","ipsum":["lorem","lorem"]}`. Semantically, I want to extract the *original* string representation for the `payload` field. I suppose it should not involve parsing the JSON string to Java objects and back to String. I don't want to risk losing the order of fields, spacing, or whatever small features because it's meant to be HMAC signed.

---

**EDIT 1:** Rephrased to clarify that this problem has nothing to do with Java String literal.

**EDIT 2:** Though it may be a bit early to say, there is no obvious off-the-shelf solution to my question in general (how to partial extract/parse a JSON string). In fact, I myself find my lazy/partial parsing theory a bit verbose. It requires way too many of passes to locate a deeply-nested node.

In particular for my situation, I found appending the signature in the body of a request a bad idea as it poses difficulties for the receiving party. I'm considering moving the signature to HTTP header, maybe `X-Auth-Token`?

**EDIT 3:** As it turns out, I was really concluding too early. Cassio's answer perfectly solves the problem by using custom deserializer and the magic `skipChildren`!

Comment: JSON spec allows order of fields to be changed. If you need exact order, use collection (array) instead

Comment: @rkosegi The JSON specification says that the ordering of fields does not affect information equivalency. This does not preclude *implementations* that parse/write JSON from maintaining order when reading or writing, which is the primary (after the muddle) request. While it may be 'dubious' to desire this maintained ordering (just as it is dubious to assume there is a 1-1 relation of the JSON text representation (and HMAC of such) and the encoded information), it fits in some domains such as diagnostic output and hand-edited configurations.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for the comments. I've updated the question, trying to eliminate confusions. Anything new? What I have in mind is a lazy mechanism to load/parse String, one layer at a time. So that in the first run, I get a "payload" and a "signature" field, both with its partial unparsed String so the "payload" part of unparsed String is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why is the order of fields or even spaces relevant for you?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin because the signature is done towards the exact string representation of the payload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could move the signature to a HTTP header to make things simpler.

However, if you want to keep the signature in the request payload, follow the steps described below.

### Creating a custom deserializer

Create a custom deserializer that can get the raw JSON string value:

```java
public class RawJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        long begin = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
        jp.skipChildren();
        long end = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();

        String json = jp.getCurrentLocation().getSourceRef().toString();
        return json.substring((int) begin - 1, (int) end);
    }
}
```

### Creating a Java class to hold the values

Create a Java class to hold the values (pay attention to the [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) annotation):

```java
public class Request {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = RawJsonDeserializer.class)
    private String payload;

    private String signature;

    // Getters and setters ommitted
}
```

### Parsing the JSON

Parse the JSON using [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and Jackson will use the deserializer you have defined above:

```java
String json = "{\"payload\":{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"ipsum\":[\"lorem\"," +
              "\"lorem\"]},\"signature\":\"somehmacsign\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Request request = mapper.readValue(json, Request.class);
```

If the `payload` is an invalid JSON, Jackson will throw an exception.

Comment: excellent! This was the answer I was looking for. Very enlightening, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theorical solution to substract your String.

You read the JSON one character at a time and count every `{` you find and every `}`, once you have the same amount of both, you have the index of the end of the block, since you have the starting index (where you have found the first opening bracket), you can substract the String. from `{` to `}`

I will work on a basic code.

EDIT :

Here is a simple code, not create for performance or to be kept like this. Just to show that this is simple.

```
public static String extractFirstBlock(String s, String key){
        int length = s.length() - 1;
        int start = -1;
        int i = s.indexOf(key); //This should be done by reading characters one by one to check if this is a key or a value.

        if(i == -1) return null;

        i += key.length();

        int cntOpen = 0;
        while(i < length){
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                if(c == '{'){ //Need to check for character into String value too
                        if(cntOpen++ == 0)
                                start = i;
                } else if(c == '}'){
                        if(--cntOpen == 0){
                                return s.substring(start, i + 1);
                        }
                }
                ++i;
        }
        return null;
}
```

It will first search for the key you ask. Then, it will read the following string to find the block and return it. If nothing is found, null is return.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(extractFirstBlock("{\"payday\":{\"fae\":\"boo\",\"ipsum\":[\"lom\",\"lorem\"]},\"signature\":\"somehmacsign\"},{\"payload\":{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"ipsum\":[\"lorem\",\"lorem\"]},\"signature\":\"somehmacsign\"}", "payload"));
    }
```

Result :

```
{"foo":"bar","ipsum":["lorem","lorem"]}
```

Improvment :

- Keep track of where the cursor is, if in a String or not
- Use same logic to find the key.
- Check for escaped character

Comment: But I still have to parse the first layer manually, right? Otherwise, how would I know the starting position of the `{` of the "payload" field.

Comment: that's not so hard. Wait a minute

Comment: haha, you got me. Technically, your `int i = s.indexOf(key);` part can be wrong as the key name can appear more than once and may not be in the first layer. But I should say, yes, your code works, at least for my immediate question. Just waiting around to see if some one has invented the wheel already, maybe my hierarchical parsing theory.

Comment: @Davyzhu Like I said, basic code. I use indexOf to limit the length of this example. Using states would be easier, first state will search the key, checking if you are not in an attribute. Then the second state will search the brackets to extract the String. But in one hour, you can have this done, checking for escaped quotes and more. Since your question is 2hours old, you would have your answer by now ;)
Even easier, find an open source JSON library, extract the code the used to read and update to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simple-json.jar` to extract that object from inside the `JSONObject`

Downloadable Jar Link - [simple-json.jar Download Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm)

Maven Jar Import [Maven Repository pom syntax](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

You actual object is

```
{
    "payload": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "ipsum": [
            "lorem",
            "lorem"
        ]
    },
    "signature": "somehmacsign"
} // hold this complete object in any string reference Variable.
```

> Here I Suppose `String jsonString` holds the complete json object as above described.

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser; 
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONObject;

// implemetation logic for extracting jsonObject.

private JSONObject extractFirstBlock(String jsonString) throws ......{

   JSONObject jsonObj, desiredObject;
   JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();  // parser to parse string to JSONObject
   jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString); // parse the Object using parse Method.
   desiredObject = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("payload"); // this Object contains your desired output which you wish to receive.

}
```

Here in `desiredObject` you will get your expected Values as JSONObject.

Comment: What is the difference between this approach and Jackson's tree model, and extract the `JsonNode`

Comment: nothing much but this perticular `.jar` what i found is more convenient and simple. only because of that i suggest you this way.. its a google api. Thanks

Comment: Then it doesn't really solve my question because the ordering/spacing can be messed up when spitting out from this `JsonObject`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap, I believe the idea is to prevent the parsing of the entire JSON, to be confirmed...

Comment: *its a google api*: I think this information is not really accurate... I would say it's a project hosted on the old Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

In Jackson , you will have to do something like below. It would read json as tokens and then you will need conditionals to decide what to do with the token. So here , i can go into the JSON extract the field "payload" and keep appending till i encounter "signature". Additionally the tokens can provide what type (it is an ENUM) of a "tag" it is  to take an action (Start , Field , Value etc.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer writer = new StringBuffer();
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\DevelopmentTools\\3.Code\\sample.json")) {
            boolean payloadFound = false;
            boolean signatureFound = false;

            JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();
            JsonParser jp = jf.createParser(fis);
            jp.nextToken();
            while (jp.hasCurrentToken()) {
                String text = jp.getText();
                if ("payload".equals(text)) {
                    System.out.println("payload found");
                    payloadFound = true;
                    jp.nextToken();
                }
                if ("signature".equals(text)) {
                    System.out.println("signature found");
                    signatureFound = true;
                }


                if (payloadFound && !signatureFound) {

                }
                jp.nextToken();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```