# How to serialize JSON with array field to object with String field?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a JSON object like

```java
{
  "id" : "1",
  "children" : ["2","3"]
}
```

And I have a Java object like (constructor, getters and setters are omitted):

```java
public class Entity {
    public String id;
    public String children;
}
```

I want this JSON to be deserialized to my Java object by this code using Jackson:

```java
Entity entity = mapper.readValue(json, Entity.class);
```

But get the following error:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
```

How can I solve it without changing type of `children` field?

The `children` field is expected to have the following value: `["2","3"]`.

Comment: Could you change the type of `children` to `List<String>`?

Comment: how do you want to store "children":["2","3"] if you dont want to change type ?? you want only first value ?

Comment: I want something like "["2","3"]"  (quotes can be with backslashes)

Comment: so you need to send json like "children":"[2,3]" , if you can, otherwise you'd need create and register custom mapper

Comment: @riso I'd like to, but I just get and parse it

Comment: I don't think you can do it with standard mapper, write custom mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating a custom deserializer

Create a custom deserializer to get the raw JSON value. You can choose one of the following implementations, according to your needs:

1. It will give you the JSON *as is*, that is, keeping all the spaces and tabs:

```java
public class RawJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        long begin = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
        jp.skipChildren();
        long end = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();

        String json = jp.getCurrentLocation().getSourceRef().toString();
        return json.substring((int) begin - 1, (int) end);
    }
}
```

2. It will give you the JSON without extra spaces and tabs:

```java
public class RawJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException {

        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }
}
```

### Annotate your class to use the deserializer defined above

Change the `Entity` class by annotating the `children` attribute with `@JsonDeserialize` referencing the deserializer defined above:

```java
public class Entity {

    public String id;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = RawJsonDeserializer.class)
    public String children;
}
```

### Parsing the JSON

Then parse the JSON using `ObjectMapper` and Jackson will use your custom deserializer:

```java
String json = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"children\":[\"2\",\"3\"]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Entity entity = mapper.readValue(json, Entity.class);
```

The value of the `children` attribute will be `["2","3"]`.

---

For more details, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38864072/1426227).

Answer (score 1):

Marshall your objects into JSON format.

Then Unmarshall from the JSON file

```
public interface MarshallingSupport {
public String marshal(Object object);
public <T> T unmarshal(String s, Class<T> t);
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JacksonJSONMarshallingSupport implements MarshallingSupport {

private final ObjectMapper mapper;

   public JacksonJSONMarshallingSupport(ObjectMapper mapper) {
       this.mapper = mapper;
       this.mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
   }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Object object) {
       try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
           } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
               throw new RuntimeException(ex);
           }
   }

   @Override
   public <T> T unmarshal(String s, Class<T> t) {
       try {
             T newObj = mapper.readValue(s, t);
             return newObj;
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               throw new RuntimeException(ex);
           }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the @Cassio's answer and if you don't want to or you can't annotate your Entity class, just add some configurations.

First create an abstract class [`for method annotation purpose you can create an interface, but in this case we will annotate a bean property so we create an abstract class, and if you also want to annotate a method in this abstract class you have to declare that method as abstract`] that will be like a mime bean for Jackson configurations:

```
public abstract class EntityMixIn {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = RawJsonDeserializer.class)
    public String children;

}
```

Now, you have to tell your mapper to take this mixin class and act like the original Entity class just for this configuration purpose:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Entity.class, EntityMixIn.class);
```

Comment: Jackson mix-in annotation is a great resource when modifying your classes is not an option. However _saying that the mix-in interface will behave like the original `Entity` is not accurate_. You can think of mix-in annotations as _a kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime to augment the statically defined ones_.

Comment: Yeap! you are right, but it is just for the example and that's why previously I said that it will be like a mime bean, but I will update this affirmation. Thank you.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. I think it's a nice contribution to the solution I had provided :)

Comment: Thank you @Cassio. I also clarified the abstract class purpose.