# Gson I can't deserialize an array which contains latitude and longitude

Tags: arrays, json, gson

I'm deserializing Json from an air quality site that has an array with latitude and longitude. The Json looks like this:

```json
{
  "geo": [
    -36.05035,
    146.942
  ],
  "name": "Albury South-west Slopes, Australia",
  "url": "https://aqicn.org/city/australia/nsw/albury/south-west-slopes"
}
```

I have written a custom deserializer which does the job but I can't deserialize `"geo": [-36.05035, 146.942]`.

My code looks like this:

```java
public static class City {
    private Geo[] geo;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public Geo[] getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(Geo[] geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public static class Geo {
    //what are the getters and setters for an array with no names just numbers?
}
```

It has me stumped 
Thanks Phil

Comment: Any exception given?

Comment: Yes it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 269 path $.data.city.geo[0]

Comment: Could you show your custom deserialiser? `Geo` class can have `lat` and `lan` properties and in `City` class you need `private Geo geo;` not `private Geo[] geo;`. In `JSON` it is an array but it is just a representation and does not represent `Java` class.

Comment: I put it up on github here: https://github.com/Philip-Shields/Air-quality

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson with custom deserializer. For reference, you can look at [Custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864072/how-to-extract-part-of-the-original-text-from-json-with-jackson)

Comment: Thanks, I would rather stick to this because it all works fine except for the nameless coordinates. I suppose I can live without the coordinates but my OCD wont let me.

Answer (score 1):

Let `geo` be a `List<Double>` instead of a nested class:

```java
public static class City {
    private List<Double> geo;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public List<Double> getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(List<Double> geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Deserialization should then be straightforward:

```java
String json = "{\"geo\":[-36.05035,146.942],\"name\": \"Albury South-west Slopes, Australia\",\"url\": \"https://aqicn.org/city/australia/nsw/albury/south-west-slopes\"}";
City city = new Gson().fromJson(json, City.class);
```

Comment: Thank you that was so simple in retrospect. I worked fine.